# how to change the map type id in google maps and how to remove the tool tip

Tags: angular, google-maps

I have created a google map in my angular project, I want to change the map type to HYBRID, how can I do that.
I have followed the official documentation, but I am not finding a way to change the view of the map
I have tried the AGM maps but the website itself is not working don't no what is the problem.
I want to remove the tooltip how can I do that.

my code:

Typescript:

```
  @ViewChild("mapContainer", { static: false }) gmap: ElementRef;
  map: google.maps.Map;
  lat = 40.73061;
  lng = -73.935242;

  markers = [
   {
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.73061, 73.935242),
     map: this.map,
     title: "Marker 1"
   },
  {
   position: new google.maps.LatLng(32.06485, 34.763226),
   map: this.map,
   title: "Marker 2"
  }
 ];

 //Coordinates to set the center of the map
 coordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat, this.lng);

 mapOptions: google.maps.MapOptions = {
   center: this.coordinates,
   zoom: 8,
   streetViewControl:false
 };

//Default Marker
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: this.coordinates,
map: this.map,
  title: '<div class="info-window">'+
      '<h3>Info Window Content</h3>'+
      '</div>'
  });

 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   this.mapInitializer();
  }

  mapInitializer(): void {
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmap.nativeElement, this.mapOptions);

 //Adding Click event to default marker
 this.marker.addListener("click", () => {
 const infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
 content: this.marker.getTitle()
 });
 infoWindow.open(this.marker.getMap(), this.marker);
});

//Adding default marker to map
this.marker.setMap(this.map);

//Adding other markers
this.loadAllMarkers();
 }

loadAllMarkers(): void {
  this.markers.forEach(markerInfo => {
  //Creating a new marker object
   const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   ...markerInfo
 });

//creating a new info window with markers info
const infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: marker.getTitle()
});

//Add click event to open info window on marker
marker.addListener("click", () => {
  infoWindow.open(marker.getMap(), marker);
});

//Adding marker to google map
marker.setMap(this.map);
 });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can provide default mapType in the map options using google.maps.MapTypeId enum.

```
mapOptions: google.maps.MapOptions = {
  center: this.coordinates,
  zoom: 8,
  streetViewControl:false,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.map.setMapTypeId(GoogleMapsMapTypeId['HYBRID']);
```

[Reference link](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native-google-maps/tree/master/documents/googlemap/setMapTypeId)

Answer (score 0):

To change map type:

```
this.map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId['SATELLITE']);
```

or

```
this.map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId['HYBRID']);
```